# best way to check if a numpy array is all non negative

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This works, but not algorithmically optimal since I dont need the min value to be stored while the function is parsing the array:

```
def is_non_negative(m):
    return np.min(m) >= 0
```

Edit: Depending on the data an optimal function could indeed save a lot because it will terminate at the first encounter of a negative value. If only one negative value is expected, time will be cut by a factor of two in average. However building the optimal algorithm outside numpy library will be at a huge cost (Python code vs C++ code).

Comment: the best solution is O(n) complexity that is to check each element one by one. min will be o(nlogn) complexity.

Comment: @YashMehta if it is sorted then it will be constant time not O(logn) just check the 0th or the n-1th (in case reverse sorted) element

Comment: Is storing _one_ additional value really that sub-optimal?

Comment: @Epis95 how calculare the minimum of a set could be in O(nlogn)? Just parse the set once and memorize the current min then you are in O(n).

Comment: Epsi95 finding the minimum is done in O(n), just as Quickbug has pointed out. Select a random value from the array as the current minimum and iterate through all elements and compare them with the current minimum (update it accordingly).

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi Even more than saving a useless storage is expected from the optimal algorithm. I edited the post to enhance that point.

Comment: You could try a `numba` version which is JIT `C` without any hassle.

Comment: Numpy does not support (efficiently) cutting the computation when a specific value is found. Apart functions like `all` and `any`, AFAIK, no other function (efficiently) cut the computation early. The standard way is generally to build a boolean array based on a user condition. This is not very efficient but flexible. It is not planed to add functions to cut the computation early because it would make Numpy very hard to maintain. If you want the computation to be cut early, then you need to do it yourself or to use another package doing that for you.

Comment: `np.any` and `np.all` do short-circuit, but they'd only be helpful if you've already got a corresponding boolean array that represents `m >= 0`. Since you don't, calculating such an array is also going to be O(n), with the drawback of requiring O(n) _space_ in addition to time (there was an answer to this question that was deleted after I pointed this out). Outside of writing a custom C++ function that short-circuits, your `np.min(m) >= 0` is the best numpy can do.

Comment: You'd *think* `np.any` and `np.all` would short circuit, but due to a performance regression, there's actually a short-circuiting inner loop and a non-short-circuiting chunk-based outer loop, so the short-circuiting ends up just skipping to the next chunk instead of terminating the whole routine. Bizarrely, you actually need to use `arr[np.argmin(arr)]` and `arr[np.argmax(arr)]` to get a proper short-circuiting "all" or "any" computation for a boolean array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pure-Numpy solution is to use a chunk based strategy:

```py
def is_non_negative(m):
    chunkSize = max(min(65536, m.size/8), 4096) # Auto-tunning
    for i in range(0, m.size, chunkSize):
        if np.min(m[i:i+chunkSize]) < 0:
            return False
    return True
```

This solution is only efficient if the arrays are big, and chunks are big enough for the Numpy call overhead to be small and small enough to split the global array in many parts (so to benefit from the early cut). The chunk size needs to be pretty big so to balance the relatively big overhead of `np.min` on small arrays.

---

Here is a Numba solution:

```py
import numba as nb

# Eagerly compiled funciton for some mainstream data-types.
@nb.njit(['(float32[::1],)', '(float64[::1],)', '(int_[::1],)'])
def is_non_negative_nb(m):
    for e in m:
        if e < 0:
            return False
    return True
```

It turns out this is faster than using `np.min` on my machine although the code is not well auto-vectorized (ie. do not use SIMD instruction) by LLVM-Lite (the JIT of Numba).

For an even faster code, you need to use a C/C++ code and use a chunk-based SIMD-friendly code, and possibly use SIMD intrinsics if the compiler does not generate an efficient code which is unfortunately rather frequent in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to use a function in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_negative(double* data, int num_elems) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elems; i++) {
        if (data[i] < 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -c -fPIC is_negative.c -o is_negative.o
```

And link with:

```
gcc -shared is_negative.o -o libis_negative.so
```

An then, in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/tmp/libis_negative.so')

a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, -3.0, 4.0])
num_elems = a.size

lib.is_negative.restype = ctypes.c_int
lib.is_negative.argtypes = [
    np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64),
    ctypes.c_int,
]

result = lib.is_negative(a, num_elems)

if result:
    print("It has negative elements")
else:
    print("It does not have negative elements")
```